# Pregnant ladies fasting during the month of Ramadan

Tags: ramadan

I would like to know if a lady is pregnant and its time for ramadan and she cant fast when does she pay her money durning the month any day or the does she pay the first day of ramadan

Comment: Hello, Ismahan. Welcome to Islam.SE. Thank you for your question. Your title doesn't really match the content of your question. Could you please [edit](http://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/8747/edit) the title to match the question you have asked?

Comment: @Daniel `What is the problem with the title

Comment: I guess you are speaking of the kafarah, what is necessary is to pay your due before the next Ramadan, how is up to you

Answer (score 1):

In the contemporary work Al Fiqh al Islami wa Adill atuhu, Shaykh Wahbah al
Zuhaili has summarised for us the legal rulings of the four main schools of thought, he states:
“If they (either the breastfeeding or pregnant woman) break their fast, 
o Making up the fast is necessary without any payment – according to the Hanafi school
o And (making up the fast is necessary) along with a payment if they fear for their child
only according to the Shafi’i and Hanbali schools
o And (making up the fast is necessary) along with a payment for the breastfeeding woman only, not the pregnant woman according to the Maliki school of thought.”

Taken from http://ramadanfastingandpregnancy.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/fasting-ramadhaan-pregnancy-breastfeeding-and-you.pdf